# OracleDataAdapter is not filling DataTable from Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

I am writing an C# application for both SQL Server and Oracle Databases that is defined in my application configuration file. When I run the code in the SQL Server environment, it works fine. I get the correct results.

The working SQL Server Code is here:

```
sqlConn.Open();
stmt = "SELECT ACTION_ID, ACTION FROM DB.ACTIONS WHERE ACTION_DATE < GETDATE() AND STATUS = 'Pending'";
SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(stmt, sqlConn);
sqlAdapt.Fill(dt);
sqlConn.Close();
```

The Oracle Code that is not working is as follows:

```
oraConn.Open();
stmt = "SELECT ACTION_ID, ACTION FROM DB.ACTIONS WHERE ACTION_DATE < SYSDATE AND STATUS = 'Pending'";
OracleDataAdapter oraAdapt = new OracleDataAdapter(stmt, oraConn);
oraAdapt.Fill(dt);
oraConn.Close();
```

I'm trying to fill the datatable dt with the results. I have tried using a DataSet first and filling the DataTable with the DataSet, but that didn't work in Oracle when it did in SQL Server. It seems like there's something simple missing.

I'm not getting any errors, I'm just getting a 0 result set from Oracle even though I know there's data there to be pulled.

Comment: what version of oracle are you using, and do you use any schema naming in Oracle ?

Comment: I'm using 10.2. The schema is "DB" in this example even though it's really something else. I'm able to run the query in SQL Developer and I get 2 results.

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product 
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production                           
CORE 10.2.0.1.0 Production                                         
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production          
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: Are you using OracleClient library from MS or ODP/Net from Oracle?

Comment: ODP.net from Oracle

using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

Comment: Well if you say 'something simple is missing', make sure you're connecting to the right server.  An easy way of doing this, is to remove the where clause, and see if data is coming back, and maybe its data from another server.

Comment: Even removing the where clause returns 0 results. The Oracle Database is on a different server than the MSSQL database. I'm getting messages from the program that i'm connecting to the Oracle server and the Oracle Database. If I remove the ACTION_ID column from the oracle database, I get a ora error saying the column is not there. When I put it back in, the query executes fine, but returns 0 results.

Comment: It was a permissions issue on the table. I had to 

    GRANT SELECT ON DB.ACTIONS TO ROLE;

The OracleDataAdapter knew the table columns, but wouldn't tell me if I had permissions to access the table even though I was logging in as the DBO.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was the DBO account I was logging into the database with did not have permissions to the table. I ran a simple grant and it worked great.

```
    GRANT SELECT ON DB.ACTIONS TO USER;
```

Answer (score 1):

Run query directly on the DB (for example using sqlplus, TOAD, SQLDEveloper etc.). Does it return anything?
If not:

a) In SQL Server text comparison (STATUS = 'Pending') is case insensitive in Oracle it is case sensitive. Maybe you have data in status column like 'PENDING' for example ?

b) Is ACTION_DATE is date datatype? If it is varchar it won't work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The query runs fine in SQLDeveloper. The field types are correct.
     Oracle: ACTION_DATE is DATE and the field value for status is Pending

Comment: Other possible reasons: 1) Maybe it is too obvious, did you inserted test data using SQLDeveloper? If so did you commited the transaction? 2) Are you using the same username to connect to db in SQLDeveloper and in your c# app? I doubt that this is the case, but it is possible to create a policy in Oracle which can show some records to one user hiding them from the other users (row level security, called VPD in Oracle).

Comment: It was a permissions issue on the table. I had to 

    GRANT SELECT ON DB.ACTIONS TO ROLE;

The OracleDataAdapter knew the table columns, but wouldn't tell me if I had permissions to access the table even though I was logging in as the DBO.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to change your code to separate the diagnostic level.

1) replace the statement with simple "select sysdate from dual;" to see if there is any row return.

2) if nothing return, it might be your connection issue. view your connection property.

3) if something is return but not fill to dataset, try to use oracle reader to throw the output and see indeed the result.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: When I change the code for the oracle section to stmt = "SELECT 1 AS ACTION_ID, 'TEST' AS ACTION FROM SYS.DUAL" I get a result in my DataTable

Comment: It was a permissions issue on the table. I had to 

    GRANT SELECT ON DB.ACTIONS TO ROLE;

The OracleDataAdapter knew the table columns, but wouldn't tell me if I had permissions to access the table even though I was logging in as the DBO.

Thank you all.